# Ursprung von "link" in der Bedeutung von "falsch"

Tags: etymology

Der folgende Satz stammt aus einer Inhaltsangabe vom Drama "Die Räuber"

> Als Daniel sich Karl zu erkennen gibt, erfährt dieser vom **linken Treiben** seines Bruders.

Offenbar bedeutet der Ausdruck soviel wie "schlechte Taten". Woher stammt er aber?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nach den [Grimms](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GL06167#XGL06167) war *link* ganz ursprünglich nicht ein Wort für die der rechten Seite entgegengesetzte linke Seite (dafür gab es im Althocheutsch *winistar*), sondern hat sich aus dem Alemannischen *lenk* für ungeschickt, langsam hergeleitet.

Die *linke* Seite war also demnach die ungeschickte Seite. Daher stammt auch das Wort *linkisch*. Bis heute ist eine umgangssprachliche Nebenbedeutung von *link* **unrecht, falsch, verkehrt, entgegen der rechten Sitten**:

> Das linke *(unrechte, falsche, anrüchige)* Treiben seines Bruders...

Comment: Es wundert mich dabei etwas, wie das mit "ungelenk" zusammenpasst, welches ja heute noch verwendet wird.

Comment: @userunknown: es ist eine andere Etymologie: *ahd.* `(h)lanca` wird zu *Flanke, Gelenk* und auch *lenken*.

Answer (score 1):

Gemäß dem [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/link) entstammt "**link**" als Adjektiv aus der Gaunersprache und bedeutet "falsch, verkehrt, anrüchig, fragwürdig; nicht vertrauenswürdig".

Answer (score 1):

Ich kann dir nicht genau sagen, woher der Ausdruck kommt; deine Vermutung was die Bedeutung angeht ist aber korrekt, siehe auch
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/link
http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/linken_taeuschen_betruegen

Meine Vermutung ist, dass der Ursprung von "link" im Sinne von "hinterhältig" einen ähnlichen Ursprung wie "recht" hat - was ja als "gut" oder "richtig" interpretiert werden kann (jegliche politische Interpretation ist in diesem Kontext zu vermeiden. Ich bin weder links noch rechts)

Wie auch immer, Google konnte mir da leider nicht viel weiterhelfen, ich habe bloß auf gutefrage.net [etwas dazu](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/warum-ist-alles-mit-dem-wortstamm-recht-gut-und-link-schlecht) gefunden.
Eine Interpretation dort stellt eine Verbindung zu Rechts-/Linkshändern her - letztere wurden ja früher zwangs-umerzogen. Ich weiß aber nicht, inwieweit diese Interpretation stimmt, sie klingt schon ziemlich abstrakt.